# Was Disney likely contractually obliged to thank Xinjiang authorities?

Tags: credits, mulan-2020

Among government authorities [thanked](https://www.cnn.com/2020/09/08/media/mulan-controversy-xinjiang-credits-intl-hnk/index.html) by Disney in the live-action remake of Mulan were Xinjiang government's publicity department and the Public Security and Tourism bureaus for Turpan.

Disney has so far refused requests to reveal details of their agreements, but do producers typically sign a binding contract that if they get assistance, then they have to thank them in the credits?

Comment: I would say it is a common courtesy. People do not need a legal contract to thank others.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that is a definite yes. While the terms of financing deals are kept secret, we should construe that to be part of their contractual obligations.

A lot of films over the past 5 years, at least that I can think of, have been relying on Chinese money to get made. Notice the slew of Chinese firms in the beginning credits?

This to me is a double edged sword. While it enables a sharing of culture in cinema, it also allows China to suppress speech that it does not like by using money in movies to dictate what can and cannot be said especially as it relates to anything regarding China or its interests: past, present, and future. I would pass on that money.

I think that is why Disney found themselves in a tough spot with Mulan.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115788/discussion-on-answer-by-j-weezy-was-disney-likely-contractually-obliged-to-thank).